# How to add a new release in Git (from svn)

Tags: git, github, svn

i would like to add a new release into a already existing repository in git.

I´ve just imported a svn repository to my local directory:

> git clone svn://111.111.111.11/software/release-1.1.1

```
cd release-1.1.1
```

then i created a new git repository (for testing purposes)

```
git init 
git remote add origin git@gitlab.info/user/temp/temp.git 
git add . 
git commit  
git push -u origin master
```

Which works just fine.

Now i have all local files pushed up to the git repository.
What i want is to push these local files, as a new (or older) release to an *already existing* git repository. I know, i could address the existing directory as git repository, but i don´t know how the files would be intermingled. I would like to tag those files, i fetched in my directory as a release(?), so there would be no misunderstanding which files belongs to which release, but since i´ve just started with git, i would not like to make a mistake and destroy anything in the existing git repository.

Is there a clear and simple way to upload the files to an existing git repository and tag them or mark them as a new release?

regards

Answer (score -1):

As i learned, as a novice, Git has no revisions. I made a workaround with tags, although that are different things. As i said i wanted to add new (and existing) files to an already existing repository and mark it, so it could be referenced by clients to pull them. After some trial and search i found the following way which works for me (except the alread existing pipelines in gitlab, but that is something nor important for this issue):

1. clone the (already existing) git repository with git clone

> git clone git@gitlab.inf/user/work.git

2. cd to work directory and add (and/or remove) the files/directories which should be added

> git add ./src

3. commit the files/dirs with the version number

> git commit -m'v1.0.17'

4. create a tag with the version number

> git tag -a v1.0.17 -m'v1.0.17'

5. Push the sources along with the newly created tags:

> git push origin -master --tags

Now the new (or "old", already in the repo) files are uploaded with the new created tag and can be distinguished and pulled. They are not interfering any existing repository.